# Min-Cut by simply cutting the lowest degree node

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have been wondering why do we need algorithms like Krager for min-cut, when we can just take the node with the lowest degree and cut it from the rest of the Graph? Considering the Graph edges are not weighted.

I cant think of a Graph where this wouldnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of examples such as [the one below](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/132):

[image]

In this (unweighted) graph, there is a $1$-edge cut (between the left half and the right half), but separating the lowest-degree node from the rest of the graph will only give you a $2$-edge cut.

More examples can be found on the [House of Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/); you can find ones like the example above by searching for

```
        Minimum Degree >= 2.0
AND     Edge Connectivity = 1.0
```

but you can vary the parameters to get different flavors of example. A very silly case is a graph with no isolated vertices but multiple connected components; in that case, by searching for cuts with more than one node on each side, we find ones that have no edges at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was putting my attention on the degree of the nodes and not on the cut itself. Also, this website is very useful, appreciate it very much :)